# Grouping by property value (and counting?) in MongoDB

Tags: meteor, aggregation-framework

I'm using Meteor for a web project, and I need to find a way to group (and count) records in a collection by one of their properties.  This is a sample record from the Collection that I ned to do this from:

```
{
    "owner" : "7YnNwSC3E3iTcRHcC",
    "isbn" : "1551110881",
    "title" : "Introduction",
    "type" : "0",
    "class" : "ADNR1234",
    "condition" : "0",
    "active" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-08-18T15:38:30.012Z"),
    "tradeFor" : {
        "isbn" : "7463849506",
        "title" : "Intro 2"
    },
    "_id" : "RFzvEdLkYxt5EmQ7s"
}
```

I know I will need to figure out a way to do...I guess it's called aggregation?  Anyway...the property I'm needing to use is "class".   I need a way to go through the whole collection and let me output each class (ADNR1234) with the number of records that have each used class as a value.

I hope I didn't ask this question poorly, I'm sort of new to Meteor, and this seems like a sort of weird problem to try to solve.

Comment: Are these documents already published to the client, or are you looking to do the aggregation on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Officially aggregation is not supported.

However people started to solve this issue:

http://atmospherejs.com/package/mongodb-aggregation?q=aggregation
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/644

Comment: you mean MongoDB aggregation is not supported in Meteor, right?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky vanilla meteor on its own doesn't but if you add in an aggregation package above you can get it working with Meteor

Answer (score 0):

Meteor exposes the mongo connection from the node driver with MongoInternals so you can use that to call aggregate.

```
var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
var col = db.collection( 'yourCollection' );
var aggregateSync = Meteor._wrapAsync( col.aggregate.bind( col ) );
var pipeline = [{$match: {}},{$group: {_id: '$class', count:{$sum: 1}}} ];
var theAnswer = aggregateSync( pipeline );
```

Documentation on [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline) also lets you apply things like sort and limit if you need them.

---

updated: Pipeline array corrected by using `$match` to select docs.  Working code up at  [Meteor Pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/xpwaJ9bHcRjofQpWL).

Comment: I attempted to use this in a server-side method, I guess that's where this is supposed to go?  And it comes up saying `MongoInternals is not defined` basically.

Comment: Yes, code is for server side.  [Other discussions on MongoInternals](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mongointernals&rlz=1CDGOYI_enAU599AU599&oq=mongointernals&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-US).  Something else is causing your error.

Comment: I will have to try it after work tonight and see what I'm doing wrong.  I'll also pastebin some console output.