# how to group by AND count several field at once in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection that looks something like this:

```
db.GE_qstat_job_monitor.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53fdf4bbe4b08d3f98fd6bcf"),
    "JB_job_number" : NumberLong(45759),
    "JB_script_file" : "/opt/UGE-8.1.7/examples/jobs/sleeper.sh",
    "JB_owner" : "root",
    "JB_job_name" : "Sleeper",
    "job_state" : "Completed",
    "submission_time" : ISODate("2014-08-26T22:27:51Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-08-27T15:17:49.564Z"),
    "wall_clock" : NumberLong(60598),
    "JB_pe" : "smp"
}
```

I need to group each document by "JB_owner" then by "job_state" (since each owner might have several job with different state) and then count how many job from each state each owner has.

I found another question here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692965/group-by-queries-on-meteor-collection) but didn't help any help or hint would be VERY appreciated :-)

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Is this running on the client or the server?

Comment: this is going to be run in the server side and I would like that looks like this

{
    JB_owner: "Juan",
    job_state:{
        Completed: 45,
        Suspended: 2,
        Running: 1,
        Queue: 0
    },
    wall_clock: 2545972,
    cpu: 0
}

Comment: I'm unclear what to do with `wall_clock` and `cpu`.

Comment: each job has a cpu and wall_clock integer value. I would like to add each value a display a total

Comment: A solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371575/grouping-by-property-value-and-counting-in-mongodb/25374474#25374474).  Working code up at [Meteor Pad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/xpwaJ9bHcRjofQpWL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your collection is called `Jobs`, this should work:

```js
var DEFAULT_DATA = {
  Completed: 0,
  Suspended: 0,
  Running: 0,
  Queue: 0,
  cpu: 0,
  wall_clock: 0
};

var jobs = Jobs.find().fetch();

var dataByOwner = {};

_.each(jobs, function(job) {
  if (dataByOwner[job.JB_owner] == null)
    dataByOwner[job.JB_owner] = _.clone(DEFAULT_DATA);

  dataByOwner[job.JB_owner][job.job_state] += 1;
  dataByOwner[job.JB_owner].wall_clock += job.wall_clock || 0;
  dataByOwner[job.JB_owner].cpu += job.cpu || 0;
});

var result = _.map(dataByOwner, function(data, owner) {
  var cpu = data.cpu;
  var wall_clock = data.wall_clock;

  delete data.cpu;
  delete data.wall_clock;

  return {
    JB_owner: owner,
    job_state: data,
    cpu: cpu,
    wall_clock: wall_clock
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it works perfectly! thanks!!! one more thing. is there a way to do this in the DB layer? since when I do `Jobs.find().fetch()` I expect thousands of element so the result array is going to be huge to work with

Comment: Here are a few suggestions: 1) Some people have done work on aggregation packages like [this one](http://atmospherejs.com/mrt/mongodb-aggregation) but I'm unclear if any are actually maintained/working. 2) At a minimum you could use a `fields` specifier with `find` and maybe try to limit the jobs to only a subset of the owners, or by date, etc. 3) You could modify the jobs schema so they are stored in a more aggregated way, or write to a separate collection which stores something like the above results and is modified whenever a job changes state.